# Cannot Get in Node Js

Tags: node.js, express, post, get

I am new to node js and creating a simple application to query data stored in database(MySql) .So what i am doing is, I have created a database named stock and i am querying it using index.html to show it at get.html but after executing the get request i am not able to get the result.
Here is my app.js

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const port= 5050;
const bodyParser=require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'));

app.post('/get',function(req,res){
const mysql=require('mysql');


const con=mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"abc123",
    database:"abc",
});

con.connect(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected");
    let sqlQuery='SELECT * FROM stock';
con.query(sqlQuery,(err,rows)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('Data Received:-');
    console.log(rows);


        });
    });
});
app.listen(port);
```

My Index.html:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My node js app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/get" method="get">
        <h1>Welcome to Stock manipulation</h1><br></br>
        Select option<select>
        <option value=0>Get</option></select>
        <input type="submit" id="query" value="get Result">
</body>
</html>
```

And my get.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Get</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the data stored at database

```
[ RowDataPacket { id: 1, type: 'BSE' },
  RowDataPacket { id: 2, type: 'NSE' } ]
```

The error i am getting after Submitting the request is[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

change

`<form action="/get" method="get">`

to

`<form action="/get" method="post">`

as you have defined the `/get` route (`app.post('/get',function(req,res){/*..*/})`)

to accept only `post` requests

Also in your `/get` route handler you should output something. Right now you do not output anything, only log to the node.js console

Comment: No luck changing Get to post

Comment: @abby, you should output something from your `/get` handler, even if it is only a test string, right now you only log to the node console you do not return anything to the web browser, try returning some html

Answer (score 0):

What is your nodejs server saying? In your routes you typically want to return some data. for example in your case your /get route res.send(data). that way your front end can show the data received. Also looks like you need to change your form to be a post not a get (Edit: As Nikos M. mentioned).

If you are new to http requests I recommend downloading Postman to get used to testing your routes requests.

Comment: Ok I will try that.